# What's the relationship between Blunt Talk and Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, production, actors

The new Starz network show [*Blunt Talk*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blunt_Talk) marks Patrick Stewarts return to television.

I was pleasantly surprised to see that the pilot episode

> features Brent Spiner as a barroom piano player

and upon looking at Wikipedia to link this question discovered

> he is listed as recurring.   [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000653/) confirms he is to appear in at least three episodes (could be many more, given that as of writing only two episodes have aired)

So what exactly is the relationship between *Blunt Talk* and *Star Trek*?   It is only through Patrick Stewart or is there some connection in the writing or production staff?

(Yes, I know this might be a better question for movies.SE, but it ***is*** on topic here and this site will generate better answers.)

Comment: it's produced by Seth McFarlane, an avowed ST:TNG fan (c.f. the Family Guy ST:TNG episode). He may just really like Patrick Stewart and Brent Spiner because they're both awesome? :)

Comment: Stewart and Spiner are close friends, one was best man at the others wedding if I recall

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The creator of *Blunt Talk*, Jonathan Ames, was interviewed by *Vogue* Magazine:

> **JESSIE HEYMAN:** Are you a big Star Trek fan?
>
> **JONATHAN AMES**: I’ve enjoyed all the iterations of Star Trek at different times in my life. I liked the original. I liked Star Trek: The Next Generation also—I remember most people really liking the whole Borg storyline. I’m not a Trekkie, but I’ve definitely enjoyed my Star Trek experience.
>
> **HEYMAN:** Data (Brent Spiner) makes a cameo appearance on the show. Did you make that casting call?
>
> **AMES**: Yes, that was my idea. One night early on in this whole thing, I had drinks with Patrick Stewart, Brent Spiner, Jonathan Frakes, and Michael Dorn. And they were all so interesting—I mean, these were four real buddies. I just thought they were all so unique and strange. As soon as I saw Brent Spiner, and I sort of knew of him through some mutual friends and I knew that he was a musician, I kind of immediately had this idea of him as a melancholy piano player.
>
> **HEYMAN:** You sitting with four of the main stars from The Next Generation sounds like something out of a dream—or a set-up for a joke.
>
> **AMES**: Oh, I know. I felt in some ways it was a little bit wasted on me because I wasn’t a total Trekkie mad man. But Seth MacFarlane is a total Trekkie. And we were able to get a hold of him. I texted him, “Get over here! With the crew of the Enterprise!” And he showed up, and I didn’t want to intrude on their night, so I just stayed for drinks and had plans afterward. But Seth stayed and just was in heaven. I kind of wanted to get all of them into the show, but I was only able to get Brent, who was wonderful. I just thought it would be fun for fans of The Next Generation to see these actors in other roles.

([Source](http://www.vogue.com/13294731/jonathan-ames-blunt-talk-bored-to-death/))

Comment: @N_Soong:  What, I just go offer any answer and mention Data and I get +10?

Comment: @ThePopMachine so I'm proud of my son; what can I say!